# How to return the string of a header based on the max value of a cell in Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Good morning guys! quick question for Openpyxl:

I am working with Python editing a xlsx document and generating various stats. Part of my script is to generate max values of a cell range :

```
temp_list=[]
temp_max=[]

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=10, max_row=508, max_col=13): 
    print(row)

    for cell in row:
        temp_list.append(cell.value)

    print(temp_list)
    temp_max.append(max(temp_list))
    temp_list=[]
```

I would also like to be able to print the string of the header of the column that contains the max value for the cell range desired. My data structure looks like this :

[image: Data Structure]

Any idea on how to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question. You want to know tha max value in each row? And in which column the value is? What about duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Thanks Bernardo for the hint. I found a decently working solution but still have a little issue. Perhaps someone can be of assistance.
Let me amend my initial statement : here is the code I am working with now :

```
temp_list=[]
headers_list=[]

for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=27, max_row=508, max_col=32): #Index starts at 1 // Here we set the rows/columns containing the data to be analyzed
    for cell in row:
        temp_list.append(cell.value)
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == max(temp_list):
            print(str(cell.column))
            print(cell.value)
            print(sheet.cell(row=1, column=cell.column).value)
            headers_list.append(sheet.cell(row=1,column=cell.column).value)
        else:
            print('keep going.')
    temp_list = []
```

This formula works, but has a little issue : If, for instance, a row has the same value twice (ie : 25,9,25,8,9), this loop will print 2 headers instead of one. My question is :

how can I get this loop to take in account only the first match of a max value in a row?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a typical INDEX/MATCH Excel problem.

Have you tried retrieving the index for the max value in each temp_list?

You can use a function like numpy.argmax() to get the index of your max value within your "temp_list" array, then use this index to locate the header and append the string to a new list called, say, "max_headers" which contains all the header strings in order of appearance.

It would look something like this

```
for cell in row:
        temp_list.append(cell.value)
        i_max = np.argmax(temp_list)
        max_headers.append(cell(row = 1, column = i_max).value)
```

And so on and so forth. Of course, for that to work, your temp_list should be a numpy array instead of a simple python list, and the max_headers list would have to be defined.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
headers = [c for c in next(ws.iter_rows(min_col=27, max_col=32, min_row=1, max_row=1, values_only=True))]

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=27, max_row=508, max_col=32, values_only=True):
   mx = max(row)
   idx = row.index(mx)
   col = headers[idx]
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much Charlie!! You made my day.